# Why is my datatable cell returning a null value?

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have an access database and a stored query. Here is my query...

```
SELECT MAX(CLNG(RIGHT(ProjectNum, 6))) AS LastDigits
FROM project_master_query
WHERE ((ProjectNum LIKE (IIF([@priorityDefID] = 4, "C*", "F*"))));
```

When I run this query, and pass in @priorityDefID of 2 for example, I get back a column name of LastDigits and one row containing a value of 1 which is correct. Here is my VB code that calls this...

```
'Project Class (Without adding unnecessary code)
Public Shared Function GenerateProjectNumber(ByVal priorityDefID As Integer) As String
    Dim dt As DataTable = ProjectSQL.GetLastGeneratedNumber(priorityDefID)
    Dim lastGeneratedNumber As Integer
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        'Exception Occurs Below: DBNull cannot be cast to other types
        lastGeneratedNumber = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(0).Item(0)) ' Or .Item("LastDigits"))
    End If
End Function

'ProjectSQL Class 
Public Shared Function GetLastGeneratedNumber(ByVal priorityDefID As Integer) As DataTable
    Dim parameterList As New List(Of DataParameter)
    parameterList.Add(New DataParameter("@priorityDefID", priorityDefID, ParameterDirection.Input, OleDbType.Integer))
    Return DAL.GetDataTableUsingReader("GetLastGeneratedNumber", parameterList)
End Function
```

Now as you can see, a row is returned but it contains a null value. When I run the query in Access and pass in the exact same value that I pass in through VB, I get the right value. When I run it through code, I get a null value. Is there anything here that stands out that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your `.Net` uses OleDb to connect to the Access db file.  OleDb (same as ADO in Access) requires different wild card characters: `%` and `_` instead of `*` and `?` respectively.

Try it this way:

```
WHERE ProjectNum LIKE IIF([@priorityDefID] = 4, "C%", "F%");
```

Note I discarded unneeded parentheses from the `WHERE` clause; you may need to add some back if I discarded too many.

Also consider whether you find `ALike` to be a suitable alternative to `Like`:

```
WHERE ProjectNum ALike IIF([@priorityDefID] = 4, "C%", "F%");
```

With `ALike`, the Access db engine *always* expects the wild cards to be `%` and  `_` regardless of the context under which the query runs ... ADO, DAO, OleDb ... it will always return the same result set.  So with `ALike` the query could work the same in an Access session as when called from `.Net` using OleDb.

Comment: Ok, this miraculously works. I am using OleDB. Now when I run the stored query in access, it returns nothing but works in my app. I left the parentheses though. Thanks for the help, been tryin' to figure this out all day.

Comment: Good.  You're welcome.  See if you find the note I added about `ALike` useful.  Personally I prefer `ALike` over `Like`, but some folks just don't seem to like `ALike`.  :-)

Comment: Never knew that. Definitely good to know, and it also works on both ends with ALIKE. Now I can move forward :)